# How to bypass cloudflare checkbox selenium in VFS Global website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, seleniumbase

There is Two type cloudflare protection, I am troubling with checkbox marking. every time I tik that chakboc it says failuer. I tried with seleniumbase and selenium also.When ever I tik that box manually or automated that shows  Failur.

Website: https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/pol/login

I tried automated code and also tried manually in automated browser. But if I tried in my normal browser then it passed the check box but it not pass in automated browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.